# set default view for ui-view in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a simple angular project structure

```
app
   index.html
   view
       main.html
       home.html
       landingPage.html
```

Index.html looks like

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ui-view>
  </div>
</body>
```

App.js file looks like

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/landingPage');
 $stateProvider.state('landingPage', {
            url: '/landingPage',
            abtract: true,
            templateUrl: 'view/landingPage.html'
 })
 .state('landingPage.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'view/home.html'
 }).state('landingPage.main', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'view/main.html'
 });;
```

and 
landing page looks like

```
    <header></header>
    <div>
            <div ui-view>
            </div>
    </div>
```

When I run the app I see the header correctly but do not see the home.html content. How do I make home.html default every time?
As you can see I have abstract true but that does not work. I also tried ng-include which works but gets error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null`

sample [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5IUbo8gzcM2DDToLYbCx?p=preview) HOME should have been displayed on running but nothing shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define another `ui-view` on your landing page as landingPage is the parent of home and main because of the `.` notation used

If you want to set a [default view for child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state) with `ui.router` there is a section with FAQ that explains it, basically you can do it via url.

Every time you go to parent state redirect it to the children state you can do it like this:

`$urlRouterProvider.when('/landingPage', '/landingPage/home');`

In code will be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@<2" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.3.1" data-semver="0.3.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('yourApp', ['ui.router']);
      app.config(
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/landingPage');
          $urlRouterProvider.when('/landingPage', '/landingPage/home');
          $stateProvider
          .state('landingPage', {
            url: '/landingPage',
            abtract: true,
            template: ' <a ui-sref="landingPage.home">Home</a><a ui-sref="landingPage.main">Main</a><div ui-view></div>'
          })
          .state('landingPage.home', {
            url: '/home',
            template: '<div>HOME</div>'
          })
          .state('landingPage.main', {
            url: '/main',
            template: '<div>MAIN</div>'
          });
        }
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="yourApp">
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rz5aInznR0k7uCKSsFxl?p=preview) example

Comment: This is what I want https://plnkr.co/edit/5IUbo8gzcM2DDToLYbCx?p=preview  you can see that HOME content is not getting printed

Answer (score 0):

Try setting url from state home to:

```
url: ''
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: What about url: ''

Comment: hmm yes it does work in your fiddle. I tried to do the same but it did not work. May be its cuz nested ui -view ?

Comment: the fiddle demo doesn't have nested states